# How to change the "Carrier name" of the Android virtual device (emulator)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I want to change the Carrier name, I have used the following command for this:

```
adb shell setprop gsm.operator.alpha BNetzA
adb shell setprop gsm.sim.operator.alpha BNetzA
```

But when I check the "NETWORK" tab of the "SIM 1" section in the [DevInfo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liuzh.deviceinfo), the **Carrier name is still on Android**